# Azure timer function that calls a webapi

Tags: function, azure, http, timer, triggers

I have to create timer function that will call particular API for every specific duration.

I don't want to use any console application for that.

In short, I have to call webapi every 10 min.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using Azure Logic Apps. It provides declarative way to schedule tasks and workflows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence

Answer (score 0):

Even your post isn't realy a question, you probably look for [Azure Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-intro).

Using Azure Scheduler, you don't even have to write a function, just enter the URL you wan't to call and specify the trigger.

Comment: Microsoft says the Scheduler is deprecated.  Don't use it. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-intro